# Bypass the global list of RequestInterceptors for one FeignClient

Tags: spring-cloud-feign, feign, openfeign

Within our microservices, we use Feign to communicate between services, we have a dedicated RequestInterceptor to handle the security and attach our JWT token to each request.

I would like to use Feign for calls to a 3rd party service outside my organization.

Let say my FeignClient looks like this.

```
@FeignClient(name = "ThirdPartyClient", url = "https://api.thirdparty.com/", configuration = ThirdPartyConfiguration.class)
public interface ThirdPartyClient { ... }
```

The problem is that this 3rd party client will also go through the list of RequestInterceptors and get the same authentication header used between my microservices.
I would  like to bypass the default list of RequestInterceptors to set a specific one.

I've tried to override the default config as described in the [doc](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/multi/multi_spring-cloud-feign.html#spring-cloud-feign-overriding-defaults), I manage to add the specific RequestInterceptor but still goes through the list and so I get all headers in the request.

```
@Configuration
public class ThirdPartyConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public RequestInterceptor requestInterceptor() {
        return requestTemplate -> {
            requestTemplate.header("Authorization", "HEADER_VALUE");
        };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the global RequestInterceptor, you can bypass authentication by checking for the feign client URL:

```
@Override
public void apply(RequestTemplate template) {
   if (template.url().equals("/your_specific_url")) {
            /*apply auth header*/
   }
}
```